# Convert mouse location to world coordinate in Processing.js

Tags: javascript, matrix, graphics, processing, processing.js

I'm making a [Rubik's Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube) game in Processing.js. I want the user to be able to rotate each face by clicking and dragging. In order to achieve this, I need to translate mouse coordinates to a ray in world space.

I tried doing this by extracting the perspective matrix from Processing, but It doesn't appear that this is possible.

Can the perspective matrix be extracted from Processing? Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't even seem to be a function to fetch the camera's *position* (it seems Processing.js follows a minimalistic interface principle). Therefore you just have to keep track of transformations yourself.

Comment: You might be looking for the `modelX()` and `modelY()` functions. They take a point in "screen space" and return a point in model space. More info can be found in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/).

Comment: @KevinWorkman this doesn't do what I need since it only works for the modelView (and not the projection matrix). However it gives me an idea to use the screen{X,Y,Z}() functions. And compute the intersection with each of the quadrilaterals in screen-space.

Comment: @cdo256 If you've figured out an answer to the question, you might want to post your own answer or delete the question.